# Intialize the value of lightning-input with function (event) in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to initialize the value of `lightning-input` with function SearchText ,fill box with a default value(using the function SearchText) .
but I don't know how

[image]

thank you for helping me

here is my code

```
<lightning-input type="text" value={search}></lightning-input>
```

```
SearchText(event,search){
    if(search === POSTALCODE_SEARCH){
        this.Adresse = this.search ;
    }               
}

connectedCallback(){ 
    this.search= this.SearchText(this.event,this.Adresse); 
  }
```

Error message:

> Uncaught Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')]

Answer (score 1):

Use `connectedCallback()`. The [connectedCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom) is a [lifecycle hook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lifecycle_hooks) in lightning web component. It fires when a component is inserted into the DOM. It runs once when the component inserted.